# How do the formula of electrostatic energy change from vacuum to with matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, voltage, dielectric

I know that, in vacuum, the [electrostic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#Energy_stored_in_electronic_elements) is:

$$
U_E = \frac12 \int  \rho(\mathbf r)\varphi(\mathbf r) d^3\mathbf{r}
$$

But I don't know how to pass to the matter version? The formula would be the same, but what is $\rho(\mathbf r)$ now?, Is it free charge or total charge (free plus bound charge) density?

P.D.: I am studying classical electrodynamics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context (which you may want to add to your question). In principle the formula is correct everywhere, provided that the potential takes account for *all the charges*.

In the context of **classical electrodynamics** this means accounting for the induced local polarization which is often reduced to dividing the field and the potential due to free charges by the dielectric constant.

In **quantum solid state theory** the equation is used as is, taking account for all the charges present (i.e. the electrons and the ions composing the matter.)

Comment: I understand your point, but i'm not understand how to apply it. I'm studying classical electrodynamics. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Elborito it is hard to be more precise, since it depends on what is $\rho$ and $\varphi$ in your equation. Yours is just general equation for electrostatic energy.

Comment: And if you have a polarization density $\mathbf P$ no dependent of the electric field $\mathbf E$, what do you suggest?

Comment: @BorisValderrama in this case, you have to evaluate the work (and if the contribution is conservative, the energy) of that polarization field. As an example, let's assume you have a prescribed "a priori" uniform polarization $\mathbf{P}^0$. You evaluate that contribution to work when you build the configuration of the system. The electric field due to this polarization is $\mathbf{E}^0 = -\frac{\mathbf{P^0}}{\epsilon_0}$, the elementary work reads $dW = -q \frac{\mathbf{P^0}}{\epsilon_0} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = - q d \left(\frac{\mathbf{P^0}}{\epsilon_0} \cdot \mathbf{r} \right) = q d \Phi^0$

Comment: @RogerVadim maybe I was drunk, because now the concept seems to be extremely easy. Thank you all for your replies